# abort product add from sales_quote_add_item observer

Tags: php, magento, observers

In my `sales_quote_add_item`-observer how would I abort the product add with a custom error message in a standard way? Obviously tried to Google it and check the core source without getting much wiser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may throw new exception. Like:

```
Mage::throwException(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote.')
        );
```

Have a look to the class and method, which dispaches sales_quote_add_item event:

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
...
public function addItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
```

It also throws the exception, which will be catched in controller after and will be displayed correctly.

Also you may try this:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()->addErrorInfo(..);
Mage::throwException(..);
```

Here is the description of addErrorInfo function:

```
public function addErrorInfo($type = 'error', $origin = null, $code = null, $message = null, $additionalData = null)
```

Comment: Didn't work. Looking through the files involved I can see that it checks `$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()` at one point, now to figure out how I can set this to something from my observer...

Comment: Have a look -- I modified my answer

Comment: Yeah, I tried `addErrorInfo` about the same time you edited, but so far no luck. The cart is using an extended ajax module for adding, I suspect that might be messing with standard behavior.

Comment: Try to disable this module and have a look if solution will work

Comment: I've made some progress. `$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getQuote()->addErrorInfo(..);` correctly sends an error instead of success - but the product still gets added to the cart! If I try and do a `Mage::throwException()` below the other code, it will proceed as a successful add. I'm confused.

Comment: Now suddenly it just worked. With `throw new Exception(__(''));`
I'm not gonna question it, just be thankful. And award you the right answer for your effort, thanks!